# Bluez 5.28 gatt server unable to register services for my device

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, gatt

I want to use my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian version 3.18.11+ with a BATTOP Bluetooth CSR 4.0 Dongle as a BLE peripheral and connect to it using an iOS device. I'm using Bluez 5.28 and the gatt_example plugin as a first step before I write a custom gatt server.

I used [this tutorial](http://gaiger-programming.blogspot.tw/2015/07/bluetooth-low-energy-customizing-gatt.html) to get it set up.

Here's how I get the bluetooth service running in verbose mode (I'm in the Bluez root directory):

```
sudo src/bluetoothd -p gatt_example -n
```

Here's the message I get after the service starts:

```
bluetoothd[2823]: Bluetooth daemon 5.28
bluetoothd[2823]: Unknown key PageTimeout in main.conf
bluetoothd[2823]: Unknown key DiscoverSchedulerInterval in main.conf
bluetoothd[2823]: Unknown key InitiallyPowered in main.conf
bluetoothd[2823]: Unknown key RememberPowered in main.conf
bluetoothd[2823]: Unknown key AttributeServer in main.conf
bluetoothd[2823]: Starting SDP server
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) hostname
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) wiimote
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) autopair
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) policy
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) neard
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) sap
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) a2dp
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) avrcp
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) network
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) input
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) hog
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) health
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) gap
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) scanparam
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) deviceinfo
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) alert
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) time
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) proximity
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) thermometer
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) heartrate
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) cyclingspeed
bluetoothd[2823]: Ignoring (cli) external_dummy
bluetoothd[2823]: Bluetooth management interface 1.7 initialized
```

Then I use these commands in another terminal window to get it advertising:

```
sudo tools/hciconfig hci0 up
sudo tools/hciconfig hci0 leadv 0
sudo tools/hciconfig hci0 noscan
sudo tools/hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 F3 4A 1A 1F 50 0F 48 FB AF AA 95 84 D6 41 D7 B1 00 01 00 00 C8 00
```

After these steps I use the LightBlue app on iOS to connect and see the services. I can see my device in the list and connect to it, but after I connect I'm not able to see any of the services in gatt-example and bluetoothd gives me the following message:

```
bluetoothd[2823]: Refusing storage path for private addressed device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_4E_8C_5E_D8_69_A5
bluetoothd[2823]: Can't store info for private addressed device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_4E_8C_5E_D8_69_A5
bluetoothd[2823]: Can't store services for private addressed device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_4E_8C_5E_D8_69_A5
bluetoothd[2823]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0001 for device 4E:8C:5E:D8:69:A5:
bluetoothd[2823]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0006 for device 4E:8C:5E:D8:69:A5:
bluetoothd[2823]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x000a for device 4E:8C:5E:D8:69:A5:
bluetoothd[2823]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x000f for device 4E:8C:5E:D8:69:A5:
bluetoothd[2823]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0013 for device 4E:8C:5E:D8:69:A5:
bluetoothd[2823]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0019 for device 4E:8C:5E:D8:69:A5:
bluetoothd[2823]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x001e for device 4E:8C:5E:D8:69:A5:
bluetoothd[2823]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0028 for device 4E:8C:5E:D8:69:A5:
```

Also when I disconnect from it, the Pi stops advertising so I have to run the previous four commands again before I can connect to it again.

I've been searching for days trying to find a solution, but I can't get it to get it working. I'd appreciate any suggestions!

I've also tried using Bluez 5.35 and 5.16 with no luck.

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out with this?

Comment: No, I switched to wifi for my connection for now. I might get back to it in a few months

Comment: Hey, I had good luck using this project on github: https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno